# How to define a custom popup / menu in vimrc?

Tags: vimrc

Assigning every useful function to a key works well for frequently used tools, but there are some operations I use so rarely, that I would prefer to assign them to some popup menu defined in my `vimrc`.

I've seen plugins like CtrlP open a popup list so this should be possible.

So my question is:

How to define a custom popup menu which can run various commands?

---

*Note: this should run in a terminal too.*

*Something like CtrlP plugin or dmenu on X11 would be ideal, where you can refine the options as you type, but a different kind of menu would be useful too.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since vim 8.2 there are native popups. The above may now be achieved without any plugins:

```
func! s:lines_count()
    echom line('$') . ' lines in buffer'
endfunc

func! s:cmdMenu()

     " variation of command-types
    let cmds = [
            \ "echom 'vim-version' version",
            \ 'call s:lines_count()',
            \ 'grep TODO'
            \ ]

    " callback for menu-popup
    func! s:selectedCommand(id, cmd) closure
        if a:cmd == -1  " menu was canceled
            return
        endif
        " execute selection; NOTE menu-items ided from 1
        exe cmds[a:cmd-1]
    endfunc

    call popup_menu(['version', 'line-count', 'TODO'], #{
            \ callback: function('s:selectedCommand'),
            \ })
endfunc

nnoremap <buffer> <silent> X :call <SID>cmdMenu()<cr>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 11):

Doing this out-of-the-box would require a fair amount of work, but I think you can do something fairly straight-forward using the [Unite.vim plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim). It provides an integration interface for creating menus from various sources. (In fact, some have even [replaced CtrlP with Unite](http://mouki.io/2013/08/15/Vim-CtrlP-behaviour-with-Unite.html).) [This example in the Unite documentation](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim/blob/9b20ab305/doc/unite.txt#L662-L674) (or take a look at `:help g:unite_source_menu_menus`, once you've installed Unite)  details how to create a basic menu of commands.

Following that documentation, I've come up with a simple example that offers a menu of commands. For demonstration purposes, I've set it up with commands for opening NERDTree (from the NERDTree plugin), showing a git blame (from the fugitive.vim plugin) and grepping for TODOs in a project (using the built-in `:grep`). I've defined a mapping to open the menu with `<Leader>c`.

```
# Initialize Unite's global list of menus
if !exists('g:unite_source_menu_menus')
    let g:unite_source_menu_menus = {}
endif

# Create an entry for our new menu of commands
let g:unite_source_menu_menus.my_commands = {
\    'description': 'My Commands'
\ }

# Define the function that maps our command labels to the commands they execute
function! g:unite_source_menu_menus.my_commands.map(key, value)
    return {
    \   'word': a:key,
    \   'kind': 'command',
    \   'action__command': a:value
    \ }
endfunction

# Define our list of [Label, Command] pairs
let g:unite_source_menu_menus.my_commands.command_candidates = [
\   ['Open/Close NERDTree', 'NERDTreeToggle'],
\   ['Git Blame', 'Gblame'],
\   ['Grep for TODOs', 'grep TODO']
\ ]

# Create a mapping to open our menu
nnoremap <Leader>c :<C-U>Unite menu:my_commands -start-insert -ignorecase<CR>
```

You can copy this into your `vimrc`, and edit the list of commands defined by the array `g:unite_source_menu_menus.my_commands.command_candidates`. Each item of the array is an array of the form `[Label, Command]`.

In my example, `my_commands` was a name I chose to identify my menu. You can use any name you'd like.

Hope this helps!

*EDIT: Added `-start-insert` and `-ignorecase` options to the mapping to make the menu start in narrowing mode (like a fuzzy-search).*